# Minimal Vagrant script to generate fully usable Debian VMs for personal computing

Tags: ubuntu, debian, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

During the past years, I configured several Debian VMs for personal usage, using either VirtualBox or Vmware.
However, I am not a sysadmin, nor do I operate any servers.

Instead, my main usage of VMs is to install "throwaway programs" or "untrusted programs" that I do not want to pollute my host system, and I definitely need a full graphical environment within these VMs.

Unfortunately, this setup has always been a painful manual process, and I always have to lookup several sites to find out how "guest extensions" and "shared volume" need to be configured. Without "guest extensions" and "shared volumes", those Debian VMs would be pretty much useless for me.

Moreover, all this "research work" felt like wasted time, because once I got everything working, I knew that future versions will be completely different.

Another pain in the ass are kernel updates of my host system (Ubuntu). In the past, I had several kernel updates that broke VirtualBox, which forced me to repeat those installations.

I also feel that clicking through the Debian installer, choosing partitions and configuring a login password is a waste of my time. I do not want any fancy installer, instead I want a Debian OS that "just works" without configuring annoying stuff like "shared folders" and "screen locking" again and again.

So my question is: I am an average developer who is not specialized in infrastructure or VMs, nor do I want to become an expert in this subfield. Using Vagrant, how can I script a Debian VM that "just works" without going through painful configuration settings again and again?

Comment: Perhaps I should ask this question to security folks who have experience with frequent VM changes and random graphical tools within VMs. If you are a sysadmin, then you are also welcome to answer this question, but please be aware that this is from a completely different user perspective.

Comment: There is a trival vagrant script which builds a fresh debian. Thiss will be okay for you for some years (until the named distro does not become obsolete). Note, the difference between the debian releases are little, the same build script will be okay, I think, maybe for a decade.